# Which camera model/generation does this Canon EOS strap belong to?

Tags: camera-straps

So I bought this second-hand camera strap at a store sellout because it looked kinda cool, has a bit of a retro vibe:

[image: canon eos strap]

I would like to know what camera model/generation this strap came from. Not sure how to research it, but I guess some people here will have seen this kind of strap before? Probably it's not as old as I think it is, but anyway ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be a Canon EW-100 BM neck strap that was offered as an optional accessory with many of the film EOS models, in the late 1980s to mid-2000s. The solid red EW-100 MA was also offered by Canon as an optional accessory concurrently with the EW-100 BM.

The EW-100 BM was the standard strap supplied with lower end models such as the 35mm film EOS Ti/300V introduced in 2002, the Rebel GII, a U.S. only model introduced in early 2003, the Rebel K2/3000V from late 2003, and the last EOS film camera, the Rebel T2 introduced in 2004. Other EOS film cameras, such as the EOS 1, EOS 1n, EOS 1v, EOS 3, and various EOS Elan models included a different strap in the box with the camera. None of the EOS digital cameras included the EW-100 BM in the box. The original Digital Rebel/300D introduced in 2003 supplied the EW-10DB II as the standard strap.

The color is described by Canon as *Marble Blue*. The strap is no longer made by Canon. References to it still exist in the accessories list on the product support pages for some older EOS film cameras and as an optional accessory on some of the earliest EOS digital models, but links to the strap are not active.

Amazon [lists it](https://www.amazon.de/Canon-2349A001-EW-100-BM-Trageriemen/dp/B000L9N8HC) in several countries but all show it as either "no longer available" or "currently unavailable." Most listings that can be found for the EW-100 BM on eBay are for used examples. Any listed as "new" are either old stock or counterfeit.

The EW-100 BM has been supplanted by several successive straps, currently the *[Pro Neck Strap 1](https://shop.usa.canon.com/shop/en/catalog/pro-neck-strap-1)*, in most markets as the official replacement strap for all older and current EOS models.

Comment: This is the right answer. Anecdotally, I have one of these straps which I got with an EOS 300X approximately in '05. When I switched to a 40D in '07, I kept this strap as I found it much more comfortable than the EOS digital strap!

Comment: So chances are it's really 1~2 decades old? Neat

Comment: The last camera that was supplied with it came out in 2004. It was still listed as an accessory in ads in the back of photography magazine through about 2006. It's probably safe to say it is at least ten years old.

Answer (score 2):

**This answer is wrong, see the one of Michael Clark.** Your strap really is blue, my bad...

Short answer : this kind of strap is still being sold with new cameras

The "retro" vibe sure looks like exposure to the sun and the associated color desaturation, my Canon 7D has a very similar type of strap (but with a second red strip).

From what I know, Canon used to like writing on the straps the model of the camera if it belongs to the *upper-class* of Canon's body:

- My old 550D just had "Canon" and "EOS DIGITAL" (or maybe just "EOS", I can't remember) written on the strap;
- My current 7D has "Canon" and "EOS 7D" written.

The single red strip may restrict the pool of bodies it can come from...

Looking on the Internet, you can find brand new strap exactly like this one, however, I'm not sure if they all are original from Canon:

- random example from Ebay with a *single red strip* (http://www.ebay.com/itm/Genuine-CANON-EOS-CAMERA-STRAP-for-Rebel-T5i-T4i-T3i-6D-7D-70D-5D-II-III-60D-etc-/110753998753), called "genuine Canon": [image]
- random example from Amazon with *2 red strips* for the 5D III ([https://www.amazon.com/Hand-Strap-Camera-Shoulder-Canon/dp/B00KZKV7KM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KZKV7KM)):
  [image]

Related info : Some photographer went to buy *no-model strap* to avoid being the target of thieves.

Comment: To be honest that's just my phone camera overexposing the image (ironic I know), sorry ^^' The strap is much darker actually

Comment: The eBay listing cited in your answer is for *used* EW-100 BM straps.

Comment: ohhh, so it really *is* blue...